# `PRAGMA ignore_check_constraints = ON;` does not work

Tags: sqlite, pragma

I have a question about PRAGMA ignore_check_constraints on sqlite3. I did setted it ON, but apparently it does not work, cause when I try to insert some data, the error "NOT NULL constraint" is raised.

Please, somebody can tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for `ignore_check_constraints`:

> **PRAGMA ignore_check_constraints** = boolean;
>
> This pragma enables or disables the enforcement of CHECK constraints. The default setting is off, meaning that CHECK constraints are enforced by default.

It only mentions `CHECK` constraints, so I assume it only applies to them, not `NOT NULL` and `UNIQUE` constraints.

Comment: Of course, sorry, my mistake. I thought it was for disable the all contraints checking, but it is only for the constraint CHECK. 

Thanks.